# How can I return a string from the list of pairs?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of pairs with word and it's length

```
list = [("This", 4), ("is", 2), ("a", 1), ("string", 6)]
```

and I need to return a string separated by spaces like

```
"This is a string"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can do that by actually trying to write some code.

Comment: You shouldn't name your variables `list` as it overrides the builtin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to get the first element (index `0`) of each tuple, and then [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them together, so:

```
' '.join(item[0] for item in lst)
```

is what you want.

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [("This", 4), ("is", 2), ("a", 1), ("string", 6)]
>>> new_string = ' '.join(item[0] for item in lst)
>>> print(new_string)
'This is a string'
```

---

Oh and by the way, don't name a variable `list`, that is why I have used a different name. It shadows the builtin.

Comment: And [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html) is not a good choice either

Comment: @thefourtheye I suppose, yes. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as:

```
print ' '.join(i[0] for i in lst)
```

Please name your `list` variable something other than list , maybe `lst`. This is because `list` is a built-in type and you can shadow its methods if you create a variable called `list`.

#### Example

```
lst = [("This", 4), ("is", 2), ("a", 1), ("string", 6)]

>>> print ' '.join(i[0] for i in lst)
'This is a string'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
>>> l = [("This", 4), ("is", 2), ("a", 1), ("string", 6)]
>>> ' '.join([i[0] for i in l])
```

Output:

```
'This is a string'
```